# Why XMPP client using strophe.js still working with out including flXHR.js?

Tags: javascript, flash, xmpp, strophe

I am using ejabberd as XMPP server,one of our project need to have a xmpp web client,for that i am referring Professional "XMPP Programming with JavaScript and jQuery" by jake moffitt i was going through chapter 3 hello world application ,here in order to make xmpp web client using strophe i have to include creating java script file such as strophe.js,flXHR.js,and strophe.flxhr.js

i have gone through example many time but failed to connect with the server,
when i checked bosh connection using localhost:5280/http-bind it is working fine!!!!!

with try and error when i try to connect with xmpp server with removing flXHR.js ,it magically got connected to xmpp server!!!!!

FLxhr.js is used for  making cross domain call as per book" Flash has a strict security policy, but unlike JavaScript, it allows cross-domain
requests to be sent to domains that permit such requests."

If i bypass above FLxhr.js i have to use a proxies

i am using apache tomcat as web-app server ,i haven't setup any proxies and not included FLxhr.js file in my html  page ,but still xmpp client is able to communicate with server!!

Can some one  please explains me what is the reason behind this??

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that your XMPP server has CORS enabled, I know Openfire now supports this. With CORS, strophe.js is able to make a cross origin request without needing the workaround provided by flash(FLxhr.js), and also works without any server side redirects.

[Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

[Cross Domain AJAX for XMPP HTTP-Binding Made Easy](http://metajack.im/2010/01/19/crossdomain-ajax-for-xmpp-http-binding-made-easy/)

[CORS Browser Support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors)

If you want to quickly check to see if your XMPP server has CORS enabled, you should be able to locate a crossdomain.xml file hosted on the root of your server.

Example:

I connect Strophe to my XMPP server using the address `http://192.168.0.26:7070/http-bind/`.

Since I have CORS enabled, I can browse to `http://192.168.0.26:7070/crossdomain.xml` and the server will return an XML file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @fpsColton ,i am using ejabberd 2.1.11 ,and may be XMPP server has CORS enabled ,i am not sure about it,but as per the book its java script restriction as it can run on the same origin where it is being kept so one need FLxhr.js in order to implement flash which can make cross domain calls,i have doubt has modern browser has ability to make cross domain calls??

Comment: Modern browsers do have the ability to make cross domain calls if the other domain correctly supports CORS. Here is a blog post by Jack Moffit on the topic, he admits to not having heard of the specification which is why his book might not have mentioned it. http://metajack.im/2010/01/19/crossdomain-ajax-for-xmpp-http-binding-made-easy/

Comment: thanks for the link in above comment ,Jake moffitt has given brief discription on cross support in modern browser and also discussed about paches for ejabbed and punjab bosh manager,nice post!